# what can be the cause of segsigv error in my program?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14

I am quite new to coding and I was trying to solve a problem in which we would be given a number of test cases (say n) and an integer (say k). So for each test case, a new integer(say a) will be given for which we have to find how many numbers (say sum) is divisible by k.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k,sum;
    scanf("%d",n);
    scanf("%d",k);
    while(n>0)
    {
        int a;
        scanf("%d",a);
        if(a%k==0)
        {
            sum++;
        }
        n--
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, is much harder to read and understand otherwise. Is this your whole code? It won't compile due to missing semi colon after `n--`, please provide a [mre] with inputs and expected outputs. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Never ignore the return code and always validate input especially when getting data from an external source. People hit the wrong button, send your program the wrong file, and maliciously attack your software looking for holes they can exploit. If you don't look, you can't catch them before harm is done. For example, what value does `n` have if the user types "BOOGERZ!"? Will `while(n>0)` be safe to run? Will `if(a%k==0)` be safe if the user provides 0 for `scanf("%d",k);`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for your response, the problem is solved now

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your valuable advice, will keep it in mind!

Comment: @SanyamJain As more general advice, learn how to turn your compiler warning level up. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oeq1oE) for example, `gcc -Wall` would have told you about all those problems in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you provide the address of the variable when scanning with `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
scanf("%d", &k);
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Also, initialise `sum`:

```
sum = 0;
```

Second, this is C++, so use `cin` and `cout` instead:

```
std::cin >> n >> k;
std::cin >> a;

std::cout << sum;
```

Comment: oh ohk so i need to use ampersand...and yes i also use cout and cin it was my first time using scanf and pintf, the problem required to process enormous data quickly and i read somewhere that scanf and printf are faster that cin and cout...thank you for your answer

Comment: @SanyamJain Please mark the answer as accepted to close the issue.

Comment: yes using ampersand atleast i am not getting runtime error but i am getting garbage values in the final result, kindly help with this as well, thank you

Comment: You only use `&` in `scanf`, `printf` doesn't need the address but the actual variable, so don't put & in `printf`.

Comment: I missed the part regarding initializing `sum`. Check it out, should be fine now. @SanyamJain